# USB dev board changes MAC address on every reboot

Tags: networking, usb, iptables, netplan, udev

beginner here,

I have a small embedded linux system attached to a linux mini-pc via a USB cable. The embedded board uses 192.168.2.2 as a static IP.

My laptop is on the LAN, the linux mini-PC is on the LAN. I have been able to set up ip forwarding on the mini-pc so that I can bounce my ssh connection to the embedded board off of the mini-pc. LAN is 192.168.1.X

1st problem is that on any power cycle (either the mini-pc or the embedded board) the embedded board changes its MAC address. I would love to be able to fix this, but I haven't been successful at this so far. Any advice appreciated.

2nd problem is that assuming I can overcome the changing MAC address issue, I haven't been able to figure out how to make a udev rule that renames the networking device to something static (aka not enx42352abb9f9d which changes the numbers each time, preferably usb_dev0), and brings that link up with an IP on the same subnet as embedded board (192.168.2.3 for example). The reason I want the interface named something useful is so that my iptables entry doesn't need to be updated manually every time. The mini-pc runs ubuntu server, doesn't have a screen attached to it. (if udev won't fix this please point me in the right direction)

Currently on every reboot I have to log into the mini-pc and do the following:

```
ip addr #copy new interface name#
sudo ip link set up dev {new interface name}
sudo ip addr add 192.168.2.3/24 dev {new interface name}
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o {new interface name} -j MASQUERADE
```

If anyone could help, or give me a push in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.

Comment: Ubuntu server 20.04 on the mini PC